# R cv.glmnet error doesn't match manual calculation

Tags: r, cross-validation, glmnet, mse

The measure reported by the model doesn't match the manual error I calculate. I am using the `cv.glmnet` function from the R package `glmnet`. I believe when I set the function variable `keep` to `True`, the cross validation fits will be kept in `fit.preval`. However, my manual calculation of mean squared error using `fit.preval` and the index of the minimum cv error doesn't match what the model summary is saying. My manual calculation is always much less.

```
library(glmnet)

x <- data.frame(runif(100),runif(100),runif(100),runif(100),runif(100))
y <- data.frame(runif(100),runif(100),runif(100))

cvfit <- cv.glmnet(x = as.matrix(x), y = as.matrix(y), keep = T, family = "mgaussian")
mean(unlist((cvfit$fit.preval[,,cvfit$index["min",]] - y)^2))
## [1] 0.08803571
cvfit
## Call:  cv.glmnet(x = as.matrix(x), y = as.matrix(y), keep = T, family = "mgaussian") 

## Measure: Mean-Squared Error 

##      Lambda Index Measure      SE Nonzero
## min 0.06003     1  0.2641 0.01158       1
## 1se 0.06003     1  0.2641 0.01158       1
```

My manually calculated mean-squared error doesn't match the models measure.

Comment: Cross-validation is a method to estimate the degree of optimism in a naive calculation of error. I’m assuming that cv.glmnet is doing a cross-validation using a set of random subsamples, perhaps a set of 90:10 splits. I’m further guessing that you just did a single calculation. Neither of these estimates are defined well enough to know where your confusion lies. You need to include your data (which would mean using `set.seed(seed)`, your results and the names of the packages you have loaded.

Comment: I provide a working example above. 0.08803571 does not match 0.2641. The specific values will change without `set.seed()` but they will always be different. `cvfit$fit.preval[,,cvfit$index["min",]]` is, to my knowledge, the predicted values at the minimum cross validation error. I did forget the package `library(glmnet)` which I have added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `mgaussian` response, cv computes the mean squared Frobenius norm of the error.
So

```
errormin = (cvfit$fit.preval[,,cvfit$index["min",]] - y)^2
mean(rowSums(errormin))
```

will match the reported error